# Align y labels in different rows of a groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, groupplots

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 4,xticklabels at=edge bottom, vertical sep=0.5cm},
    minor tick num = 1,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    width = 7cm,
    height= 5cm
]

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = {Out 1}]

\addplot [
    domain=0.0001:2, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    line width = 1.2pt,
    ]
    {-(x*x*x)/36};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = {Out 2}]

\addplot [
    domain=0.0001:2, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    line width = 1.2pt,
    ]
    {-(x*x*x)/36};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = {Out 3}]

\addplot [
    domain=0.0001:2, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    line width = 1.2pt,
    ]
    {x/100};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = {Out 4}]

\addplot [
    domain=0.0001:2, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    line width = 1.2pt,
    ]
    {-1+(x*x)/50};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

How can I make it so that the "Out n"s are aligned?

Comment: One way is to define width of `ytick` lables.

Comment: One problem per question pleas! Where should be `10^{-2}`? Do you like omit vertical space between diagrams? In my answer I didn't consider this request sinvce they are unclear to me.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry! Just edited out the second question. I think I've seen solutions to it here before. If I don't find any, I'll post a new one and let you know =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Meanwhile I figured out your sub questions. Suggested solution below now solve them too!

Just spell out my comment. Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size=1 by 4,xticklabels at=edge bottom, vertical sep=0cm},
    width = 7cm,    height= 5cm,
    grid=major,
    minor tick num = 1,
    yticklabel style = {scaled ticks=false,  % <---
                        text width=2.4em, align=right},  % <--- added
    domain=0:2,
    samples=51,  
    no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=red}
                ]

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = Out 1]
\addplot    {-(x*x*x)/36};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = Out 2]
\addplot    {-(x*x*x)/36};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = Out 3,
               /pgf/number format/fixed
               ]
\addplot    {x/100};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel = Out 4]
\addplot    {-1+(x*x)/50};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- main changes are added `scaled ticks=false` to `yticklabel style` and `/pgf/number format/fixed` to the third diagram, however it can be part of `groupplot` options too. This two changes remove scale factor at third diagram.
- As you can see, I wee bit shortened your code, i.e. move all common styles (reduced number of samples, a changed domains, curves widths and colors) to `groupplot` options. To they I also add `no marks` option.